# Which of these functions are one-to-one and why?

Tags: functions

Where x and y are in the set of all integers:

```
1. f(x,y) = 2x − y
2. f(x,y) = x^2 − y^2 
3. f(x,y) = x^2 − 4
```

Here are my answers:

```
1. True
2. False (counterexample would be (-2,-2) and (2,2) which result in same value
3. False (counterexample would be (-2,1) and (2,1) or (2,7), etc
```

Can someone tell me if these are correct and tell me how to prove if it for the functions that are one to one?

Comment: That's what I deduced, but how do I formally prove it for the ones that ARE injective?

Comment: Are the functions from $\mathbb Z^2$ to $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: they are from Z x Z to Z

Comment: Those containing a square are not.

Comment: For the first one, $f(0,0)=0=f(1,2)$ but $(0,0)\neq (1,2)$

Comment: Wait so none of them are injective/one to one?

Comment: Ya, none of them. To prove injectivity, you need to make assumption that $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ and you need to prove that $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$

Comment: Sweet. Thanks!!

Comment: I can't see any function. What are the domain and codomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is not one to one, since $f(2,2) = f(1,0)$.
2. and 3. are also not one to one, as you correctly showed.

Comment: Ah cool, I guess that makes me avoid having to prove it. But how would I prove a function is one-to-one formally if there was one?

Comment: @Thandor7765 By assuming that $f(a)=f(b)$ and proving that therefore, $a=b$. For example, if $f(x)=x$, then it is simple to show that $f$ is injective. Take $x,y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. But then, since $x=f(x)$, you have $x=f(x)=f(y)$, and since $f(y)=y$, you have $x=f(x)=f(y)=y$, therefore $x=y$, so $f$ is injective.

Comment: @Thandor7765 Naturally, things get trickier for more complicated functions, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: For some reason I thought it would be different for functions that had multiple variables, but I guess not

Answer (score 2):

1. f(4,1)=f(3,-1)=7.
2. f(1,1)=f(-1,-1)=0.
3. f(1,1)=f(-1,1)=-3.

none of them is one to one.